# Jena Sparql and construct

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

`CONSTRUCT` is an alternative SPARQL result clause to `SELECT`. Instead of returning a table of result values, `CONSTRUCT` returns an RDF graph.  For instance, running this query in the following Java code produces an `HttpException: 406 Unacceptable`. But if instead of the `CONSTRUCT` block, I choose `SELECT ?x`, it's just fine. Does Jena support `CONSTRUCT`, and if so, how?  Both queries are acceptable to the [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/snorql).

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

CONSTRUCT { 
    :France onto:anthem ?x
}

WHERE
{
  :France onto:anthem ?x .
}
```

```java
Query query = QueryFactory.create("the query goes here");
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql",     query);
ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();  
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jena supports `CONSTRUCT`, but to get the result you need to call a different method, because `execSelect` and `ResultSet` are only for `SELECT` queries. Use this instead:

```
Model results = qexec.execConstruct();
results.write(System.out, "TURTLE");
```

`Model` is Jena's interface for accessing RDF graphs, see the [javadocs](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) for details.

Comment: worked perfectly, the write method does all the work for me, thx

Answer (score 2):

ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query)  cannot find symbol and identifier expected error occurs at this point