# One SPARQL endpoint for Select, Describe and Construct using Jena ARQ

Tags: sparql, jena, arq

I have built a simple webpage as the frontend user interface for users to enter the sparql query. I am using Jena ARQ as the backend (I am using Grails) sparql query engine. Currently, users can only enter a "Select" query and I use:

```
ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
```

to execute the query and return the result. But now, I also want users to send Describe and Construct query from the same page to the backend. As has been discussed in this thread: [Jena Sparql and construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976809/jena-sparql-and-construct), we need to use

```
Model results = qexec.execConstruct()
```

at the backend. So my question is, at the backend, how can I know if the query string is a Select query, a Describe Query or a Construct query, so that I can select from execSelect(), execDescribe() or execConstruct()? Is there anything I need to change for the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Query class](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/Query.html) has methods for finding out the type of the query:

```
if (qexec.getQuery().isSelectType()) {
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
    // ...
} else {
    Model results = qexec.execConstruct();
    // ...
}
```

To be complete, you should probably handle `DESCRIBE` and `ASK` as well.